# Getting errors while building Maven project in Netbeans?

Tags: java, apache, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I get these errors while trying to build a Java EE(Maven) project in Netbeans (Also got the same error building from cmd with `mvn clean install -U`)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project myproject: There are test failures.
```

The wierd thing is, I get the same error while trying on my other PC, but, when I tried building at school there was no error and it worked fine . There is zero test errors in school.

Why is this happening? Does anyone have any idea?

And sorry if this question is a "bad" stackoverflow question, but I have nowhere to turn to get help.

EDIT:

Now Im getting this:

`Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`

which is good, but Im still getting this error and build failure:

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) on project backend: Execution attach-sources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:jar:2.4 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]`

And at the beginning of the build I am getting these warnings:

```
Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for edu.cth.myproject:backend:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

`build.plugins.plugin.version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin is missing.
build.plugins.plugin.version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing.
build.plugins.plugin.version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing.
It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.`

I dont know what to do?

Comment: Tests can fail on some platform and not on others for a whole lot of reasons. I suggest you reduce your problem to a single failing test and post it here.

Comment: @Tunaki this is the first line of error: `Local Exception Stack:
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.`

Comment: Add -X option and look carefully at the output console.

Comment: @lametaweb Will try that!

Comment: "Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527" speaks for itself. You have a test that is trying to connect to a localhost server and it fails. Is this server correctly up and running? Is it correctly accepting inputs from port 1527? Is this port open?

Comment: @Tunaki Please check the EDIT of the post I made.

Comment: For now the maven warnings are not important to your problem.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen But I still have that error and build failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have test failures.  This mean that code explicitly designed to test if things are working, now say that it doesn't.

Investigate the test report to find out what the failures are - this is probably easiest from within Netbeans (tell it to run the tests).  This could be just about anything.   My *guess* would be that the tests try to talk to a server on the schools network you cannot reach from home, but you need to investigate to be sure.

---

EDIT:  The error message posted in the comments says the code expected a database server running on port 1527, but none were.

Apparently this is the Derby database (which is available in a slimmed down version in the JDK), and you need to invoke the server manually.  You may have received information from your teacher about how to set this up correctly.

This youtube video claims to say "How to fix netbeans database port 1527 error".  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DM7g0hm_s4w

Comment: I think so too, it seems to be Jdbc errors. this is the first line of errors: `Local Exception Stack: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect`

Comment: Will it work if I VPN to the school network? Sorry if stupid question, but Im new to this.

Comment: can you post what exactly error is? It might be you are not having DBMS server installed on your system.

Comment: @Imran and Thorbjörn Please check the EDIT I did to my post

Comment: Just saw your Edit to the post. I did manually invoke the server, but I have diffrent errors right now, that I now included in my post above.

Comment: Thanks Thorbjörn! What you said about the Derby database, plus doing some changes in admin console for glassfish I was able to fix my problems. Thanks!